La valeur temporelle du plus-que-parfait vs. plus-que-parfait du subjonctif (la simultaneité ou l'antériorité ?)
La question est motivée par cette phrase issue de Le Comte de Monte-Cristo (dont la relecture est motivée par avoir vu le film - mais il s'agit de la première fois que je le lis en français):

Villefort n’eut donc de son roi qu’une reconnaissance non seulement inutile pour le moment, mais même dangereuse, et cette croix d’officier de la Légion d’honneur, qu’il eut la prudence de ne pas montrer, quoique M. de Blacas, comme le lui avait recommandé le roi, lui en eût fait soigneusement expédier le brevet.

(soulignement ajouté)
Je suis perturbé par l'utilisation du plus-que-parfait du subjonctif (eût fait) à côté du plus-que-parfait (avait recommandé). Les deux événements précédent la proposition principale (eut), ce qui justifie l'utilisation de formes plus-que-parfait. Mais l'ordre chronologique des deux formes ne me semble pas évident :

selon le texte la recommandation du roi arrive avant l'expédition de brevet;
néanmoins, en isolement, j'aurais tendance à voir la recommandation comme étant continue en temps (est-ce qu'une telle valeur est possible pour le plus-que-parfait ?) pendant l'expédition
finalement, le subjonctif pourrais avoir la valeur du future-en-passé, par rapport à l'autre proposition

J'apprécierais l'explication et/ou une référence définitive sur l'usage des formes passé/imparfait/plus-que-parfait du subjonctif à côté de l'imparfait.
Questions liées :
Le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif
Plus-que-parfait du subjonctif
Remark
Interestingly, the first English translation I consulted, completely omits the problematic parallel action expressed by plus-que-parfait (avait recommandé):

Villefort, therefore, gained nothing save the
king’s gratitude (which was rather likely to injure him at the present time) and the cross of the Legion of Honor, which he had the prudence not to wear, although M. de Blacas had duly forwarded the brevet.

Whereas a Russian translation uses a verbless phrase:

Поэтому награда, которую Вильфор получил от своего короля, была не только бесполезна, но и опасна, и он никому не показал своего ордена Почетного легиона, хотя герцог Блакас, во исполнение воли короля, и озаботился выслать ему грамоту.

C'est pourquoi la récompense que Villefort reçut de son roi était non seulement inutile, mais aussi dangereuse,
et il ne montra à personne sa Légion d'honneur, quoique le duc de Blacas, en exécution la volonté du roi, et prit la peine de lui envoyer une lettre.


German version uses a simple past in the subordinate, and plus-que-parfait for the king's will:

Augenblick nicht bloß nutzlos, sondern sogar gefährlich
war, und er war so klug, jenes Offizierskreuz der Ehrenlegion
niemand zu zeigen, obwohl ihm Herr von Blacas sorgfältig das
Diplom ausfertigen ließ, wie es der König befohlen hatte.

(Google translate seems to do poor job with this German sentence.)
Italian largely follows French:

Villefort non ebbe dunque dal suo Re che una riconoscenza non solo
inutile per il momento, ma ben anche pericolosa, e quella croce di
ufficiale della Legion d'Onore ottenuta, ebbe la prudenza di non
mostrarla, quantunque de Blacas, come gli aveva raccomandato il
Re, ne avesse fatto spedire sollecitamente il brevetto.


Si c'est la concordance des temps qui pose pb: remplacer quoique par pourtant, ce qui ne change pas le sens. Pourtant M. de Blacas [...] lui en avait fait soigneusement expédier le brevet. C'est sûrement expliqué dans Bled.

@FrançoisJurain la question concerne la simultaneité (ou non) de deux propositions subordonnées (avoir recommanndé et eût fait expedier). Il me semble que votre commentaire (et la reponse par at_None) s'addressent seulement la relation entre la proposition principale et la subordonnée (c.a.d., l'utilisations de plus-que-parfait et du subjonctif.)

La concordance des temps prend en compte la relation temporelle entre subordonnées. Les parties de la citation que j'ai omises dans mon 2ème commentaire sont inchangées si je remplace quoique par pourtant: tout à l'indicatif, passé simple ou pqp. Sous cette forme, on voit bien que l'offre (les temps grammaticalement disponibles) ne suffit pas à déterminer dans quel ordre le roi recommande et Blacas expédie: faut aussi que le lecteur travaille du chapeau.

@FrançoisJurain transposé au présent : il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi l'avait recommandé ou il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi le recommandait ?

@FrançoisJurain du point du vue de logique, je ne verrait pas du mal à utiliser un temps surcomposé (comme le roi l'avait eu recommané). Mais votre commentaire que le temps grammatiqualement disponible ne suffit pas, pourrait être la reponse (plutôt que la commentaire.)

Je crois que votre post cherche à ratisser trop large et gagnerait en utilité en énonçant un problème précis et concret. P. ex., celui énoncé ds le commentaire que j'ai upvoté est impeccable. Ou un autre, p. ex. comparer la logique de concordance des temps en français et russe: en tous cas un seul.

@RogerV. On peut dire les deux: il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi l'avait recommandé et il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi le recommandait.

... qu’il eut la prudence de ne pas montrer, quoique M. de Blacas, comme le lui avait recommandé le roi, lui en avait fait soigneusement expédier le brevet me semble acceptable aussi.

Quoique introduit la concession. Les subordonnées exprimant la concession sont en général au subjonctif.

Les propositions subordonnées de concession sur Lingolia.

Grammaire du français contemporain1 :



Les conjonction de concession sont ǫᴜᴏɪǫᴜᴇ (plus fréquent dans la langue parlée) et ʙɪᴇɴ ǫᴜᴇ. [...].
Mode :  C'est le subjonctif obligatoire depuis la fin du XVIIe siècle. Quand on rencontre l'indicatif futur, ou le conditionnel, c'est presque toujours parce que ǫᴜᴏɪǫᴜᴇ et ʙɪᴇɴ ǫᴜᴇ sont employés avec une valeur de conjonctions de coordination [...]


Le bon usage2 :


Le verbe de la proposition d'opposition se met
a) au subjonctif dans la plupart des cas, même d'une manière générale, quand il s'agit d'un fait réel.


Blog chroniques Grevisse L'emploi du subjonctif dans les subordonnées concessives :


La concession s’exprime au moyen des conjonctions « bien que, quoique » (voir aussi le post sur « malgré que »), et dans des structures corrélatives plus complexes, comme « tout...que, si...que, quelque...que, quoi...que ».


Dans cette relation où le procès subordonné est envisagé, le subjonctif est dominant : « Don Lockwood danse dans la rue, bien qu’il pleuve ». La pluie n’empêche pas le personnage de danser. Cependant, on a hésité entre le subjonctif et l’indicatif jusqu’au 18e siècle, et même après, notamment dans la langue familière. On rencontre dans la subordonnée le futur ou le conditionnel, qui sont plus aptes que le subjonctif à exprimer des nuances dans l’avenir : « Si cruels qu’ils pourront être, leur bêtise fera pâlir leur cruauté » (P. Valéry). Cela étant, le subjonctif est préférable dans les concessives, quoi qu’on dise.

L'imparfait du subjonctif marque l'antériorité par rapport au passé simple de la principale (eut). Si ce verbe avait été au présent on aurait le passé du subjonctif pour marquer cette antériorité :
Villefort n’a  de son roi qu’une reconnaissance inutile quoique M. de Blacas lui en ait fait soigneusement expédier le brevet comme le lui  avait recommandé le roi
Pour répondre aux questions en commentaire :



le plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif (avoir recommandé) et le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif (eût fait expédier) semble être au même niveau d'antériorité par rapport à la proposition principale.



Non, le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif est ici antérieur au plus-que- parfait de l'indicatif. C'est aussi une question de logique, la recommandation d'expédition et l'expédition elle-même peuvent être quasi simultanées mais l'une entraîne l'autre et il y a antériorité marquée par les temps.



transposé au présent pourrait-on avoir : il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi le recommandait ?



Non. Dit ainsi l'imparfait indiquerait une habitude, une généralité (comme le roi le recommandait habituellement / dans un tels cas).



Pourrait-on dire : le roi l'avait eu recommandé.



Non. Un plus-que-parfait surcomposé marquerait une rupture d'habitude (il l'avait eu recommandé mais il ne le fait plus).

1 Larousse, 1964.
2 10e édition,1975,§1032.

Merci. Ce qui me perturbe est que le plus-que-parfait (avoir recommandé) et le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif (eût fait expedier) semble être au même niveau d'antériorité par rapport à la proposition principale, comme s'il s'agissait de deux actions simultanées (ce qui ne pas le cas.)

COmme je l'avais exprimé dans les commentaires à l'autre uttilisateur: transposé au présent : il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi l'avait recommandé ou il a fait expédier le brevet comme le roi le recommandait ?

Pourrais-t-on dire le roi l'avait eu recommandé ?

Merci beaucoup, c'est claire maintenant.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


(LBU § 999) Dans la langue écrite, et surtout dans la langue littéraire, le
subjonctif a quatre temps : le présent, le passé, l'imparfait et le plus-que-parfait.  Leur usage dans les propositions est régi par ce que l'on appelle la concordance des temps.
Brunot a écrit, dans une formule percutante : « Ce n'est pas le temps
principal qui amène le temps de la subordonnée, c'est le sens. Le chapitre de la concordance des temps se résume en une ligne : Il n'y en a pas. » (Pensée, p. 782.) Il ne s'agit pas, en effet, de quelque chose de mécanique : voir par ex. § 899, b et c. — D'autre part, on parle aussi de concordance des temps dans la phrase complexe lorsque les verbes sont à l'indicatif ; mais les relations du
verbe d'une proposition avec le verbe principal ne diffèrent aucunement de celles qui unissent les verbes se trouvant dans des phrases successives ; en outre, le rapport avec le moment de la parole est un élément essentiel. C'est parce que le subjonctif est employé surtout dans des propositions que l'on a voulu établir à son sujet des concordances mécaniques avec le verbe principal.
a)  Lorsque le verbe principal est au présent ou au futur, on suit les règles données au § 897 : on met le présent quand le subjonctif exprime un fait qui est simultané ou postérieur par rapport au verbe principal ; on met le passé quand il s'agit d'un fait antérieur.
b) C'est quand le verbe principal  est au passé qu'il y a un usage propre à la langue écrite.
Elle emploie l'imparfait quand le subjonctif exprime un fait qui
est simultané ou postérieur par rapport au verbe principal :
J'ordonnais (ou j'ordonnai, j'ai ordonné, j'avais ordonné, quand j'eus ordonné) qu'il PARTÎT sur le moment, qu'il PARTÎT sans tarder.
Elle emploie le plus-que-parfait quand le subjonctif exprime
un fait qui est antérieur par rapport au verbe principal :
Je regrettais (ou je regrettai, etc.) qu'il FÛT PARTI depuis une heure.


(LBU § 844) Le plus-que-parfait.
a) Valeur générale. Le plus-que-parfait exprime un fait accompli qui a eu lieu avant un autre fait passé, quel que soit le délai écoulé entre les deux faits :
Dès Bodenbach, où sont les douanes autrichiennes, les allures des employés de chemin de fer m'AVAIENT MONTRÉ que la raideur allemande n'existe pas dans l'empire des Habsbourg (APOLLIN., Hérésiarque et Cie, p. 105), — Alain tourna la tête [...] vers la porte-fenêtre béante d'où venait une douce odeur d'épinards et de foin
frais, car on AVAIT TONDU les gazons dans la journée (COLETTE, Chatte, p. 203).
— Elle se demandait si elle AVAIT MONTRÉ assez de hargne à l'égard de la Grande-Bretagne (DÉON, Taxi mauve, p. 207). — Le fait est accompli par rapport à un
repère appartenant au passé et explicité par un complément de temps : Une heure après, Ruy Diaz AVAIT TUÉ le comte (HÉREDIA, Troph, Serrement de mains).

Dès [que nous fumes arrivés à] Bodenbach … : le fait passé est l'arrivée à Bodenbach ; à l'arrivé dans cette ville le fait de montrer que la raideur allemande n'existe pas est accompli. Au moment où l'odeur de foin était perceptible, la tonte du gazon avait déjà pris place. L'action de tondre le gazon est antérieure à celle sentir le foin. L'action de montrer de la hargne est une action  accomplie au moment où  elle se demande si cette action répondait à un certain critère, ce qui est dans le passé (« demandait »), donc le plus-que-parfait s'ensuit.
En admettant que « continue en temps … pendant l'expédition » signifie que l'action prend place pendant le temps que l'action de l'expédition prend place, on a le résultat que ce qui est recommandé est déjà en train d'être fait ; de plus, le temps de faire la recommandation est bien moins long que celui de l'expédition. Il y a donc une pensée aberrante dans le fait d'avoir «  tendance à voir la recommandation comme étant continue en temps  pendant l'expédition » ; mais le plus-que-parfait n'a pas cette valeur.
C'est l'imparfait qui montre un fait en train de se dérouler.

(LBU § 881) a)
Valeur générale. L'imparfait montre un fait en train de se
dérouler dans une portion du passé, mais sans faire voir la fin
du fait (ni souvent le début).

L'utilisation de l'imparfait donne cette impression de simultanéité, mais elle est incompatible avec les actions : l'expédition n'est qu'un point dans le temps, et de plus la recommandation représente aussi un point dans le temps.

Villefort n’eut donc de son roi qu’une reconnaissance non seulement inutile pour le moment, mais même dangereuse, et cette croix d’officier de la Légion d’honneur, qu’il eut la prudence de ne pas montrer, quoique M. de Blacas, comme le lui recommandait le roi, lui en eût fait soigneusement expédier le brevet.

Si on modifie la phrase de sorte que les actions soient compatibles avec le critère relatif au faits en train de se dérouler, alors l'imparfait convient pour cette notion.

Villefort n’eut donc de son roi qu’une reconnaissance non seulement inutile pour le moment, mais même dangereuse, et cette croix d’officier de la Légion d’honneur,

qu’il eut la prudence de ne pas montrer,

quoique M. de Blacas,

comme le lui  demandait le roi, (s'attendre à quelque chose d'heureux, de favorable de la part de quelqu'un., TLFi)

lui eût rappelé souvent de la porter.



La raison du vote négatif ?

NMDV mais j'avoue avoir du mal à suivre ta réponse. Je suis un peu perdu entre l'odeur du foin et les pensées aberrantes.

@jlliagre C'est plus lisible maintenant.
